# App Version Plugin Issue

Tags: javascript, telerik, cordova-plugins, telerik-appbuilder

I am trying to get App Version in a Telerik Hybrid Application and the code that i am using is as follows

```
cordova.getAppVersion.getVersionNumber(function(value) { alert(value) });
```

This was working in iOS 9.3. But after updation of iOS 9.3.1, i noticed that the plugin is not giving me Version Number.

Can someone help me with this issue

Answer (score 0):

I've responded on the GitHub repo - please take the discussion there https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/AppVersion/issues/3